# $c + b^Tx + x^TAx = 0$. Is there a general solution for x?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratic-forms

I have an equation which looks like :
\begin{align}
c + b^Tx + x^TAx = 0
\end{align}
Where  $c \in \mathbb{R}, b \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} $ are known. Is there a general solution to this problem for $x$ ?

Comment: Something is wrong, c and $x^TAx$ are scalars, $b^T$ is not.

Comment: Thank you I forgot the x after $b^T$ !

Comment: It is a quadratic expression in 2 variables i.e. a conic or pair of lines of some sort, depending on A.

Comment: Yes and I would like to find the value of x for this general quadratic form, or know if there is no general solution.

Comment: Your equation is simply the equation of a general conic written in matrix form, which of course has a solution, a non-degenerate conic (parabola/ellipse/circle/hyperbola) or a degenerate one (pair of straight lines); I suggest reading more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Matrix_notation) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections).

Comment: Not just one general solution. In general we will get a level-set or surface of solutions. Do eigenvalue decomposition on $A$, switch basis and you will have the solution on a neater form. Second degree will ensure we will have the classical conic sections. Circles, ellipses, parabola and hyperbolas and pairs of lines. The eigenvalue decomposition will find the dimensions of elongation of ellipses (smallest / biggest radius), or the dimensions of the lines et.c.